# Error: Could not find or load main class scala in intellij IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile this code but it gives me an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class clickstream.LogProducer
```

Here is a screen for my code

[image: intellij]

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of posting a screenshot. This is very hard to read.

Comment: its because the code i copied it from GitHub and I think the problem is not with the code that's why I posted just a screenshot. i will post the code for you. thank you

Comment: @BilalBouhila; If this specific code is not the problem then please don't post it. Post the smallest, simplest code that creates the problem. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

try to rebuild the project, alternatively build on command line.

Comment: this works most of the time.. i always build on command line and it works perfectly.